# Upper and Lower Integrals, rational and irrational

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational & $-x$ if $x$ is irrational, find the upper and lower integrals on the interval $[0,1]$.

I think its $\frac{1}{2}$ for upper and $-\frac{1}{2}$ for lower but could someone verify?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Since both the rationals and irrationals are dense in $[0,1]$, every nonempty interval contains a member of each. Thus the supremum of the values of $f$ in any interval of a partition is the same as it would be if you were simply integrating $f(x)=x$, so the upper integral is $\int_0^1xdx=1/2$. By an analogous argument you find that the lower integral is $-1/2$.